# How could the app send a message to the phone when certain mission fulfilled?

Tags: firebase-cloud-messaging

I can use FCM console to send messages to all users or certain users at a certain time.
Now I want the app send a message to specified users when their in-game energy is full. How to realize it with FCM? And can I know the messages' sends, opens, conversions?

Answer (score 0):

Sending a message to a user can only be done from a trusted environment, such as the Firebase console, or a place where you can trust that the code running is yours (such as your development machine, a server that you control, or something like Cloud Functions/Cloud Run).

For examples of how to send a message by calling FCM's API, see the documentation on [building send requests](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message), and this sample use-case of [notifying the user when something interesting happens](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/use-cases#notify_users_when_something_interesting_happens) using Cloud Functions.

Comment: Thanks very much. Seems to be the right way.